# Jackson JAXB JSON marshalling/unmarshalling

Tags: json, jaxb, jackson

I am trying to develop a REST server using Jackson and JAXB.

I have the following POJO class:

```
class Location {
    double[] latLng;
    String address;
}
```

In order to make input formats short and flexible, I would like the JSON input to be either of the following formats:

```
{ "location": [33,75] }

{ "location": "complete address" }
```

And the output to always be in the format:

```
{
    "location": {
        "latitude": 33,
        "longitude": 74,
        "address": "complete address"
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks,
Asim

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, well, almost. =)

Suppose the wrapper class for `Location` is `Data`:

```
class Data {
    Location location = new Location();
    public Data() {}
    public Location getLocation() { return location; }
    public void setLocation(Location value) { location = value; }
    public void setLocationGPS(double[] value) { location.latLng = value; }
    public void setLocationAddress(String value) { location.address = value; }
}
```

With this definition, any of the following input JSONs will be accepted:

```
{ "location": { "latLng": [33,74], "address": "complete address" } }

{ "locationGPS": [33,74] }

{ "locationAddress": "complete address" }
```

=)